# How to concatenate the variable value to an xpath in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a requirement to fetch the values by concatenating variable value to the xpath.
Here is my XML file

```
<ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
    <ns1:name>ABC</ns1:name>
    <ns1:numberInParent>1</ns1:numberInParent>
</ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
<ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
    <ns1:name>DEF</ns1:name>
    <ns1:numberInParent>1</ns1:numberInParent>
</ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
.
.
.
<ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
<ns1:name>ABC</ns1:name>
<ns1:mainProductTitle>
        <![CDATA[ABC]]>
</ns1:mainProductTitle>
</ns1:specificationSectionDetail>.
.
.
<ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
<ns1:name>DEF</ns1:name>
<ns1:mainProductTitle>
        <![CDATA[DEF]]>
</ns1:mainProductTitle>
</ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
```

I'm trying to loop through each of the product specification component and get the value of ns1:name element and store it in a variable.
using the variable value i need to find the ns1:mainProductTitle value for that vaule stored in the variable.

My XSL file looks like

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:productSpecificationComponent/ns1:parent[text() != 'true']/../ns1:name[text() != 'Parent']/..">
    <xsl:variable name="subItem" select="ns1:name/text()"/>
        <Item>
                <LongDescription>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:specificationSectionDetail/ns1:name[text() = ''' , $subItem , ''']../ns1:specificationSectionFoodOtherLabellingCopySection/ns1:mainProductTitle/text()')"/>
                </LongDescription>
        </Item>
```

The output i'm getting is not as expected, as it just returns the path name and not the value

```
<Item> 
<LongDescription>ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO/ns1:specificationSectionDetail/ns1:name[text() = 'ABC']/ns1:specificationSectionFoodOtherLabellingCopySection/ns1:mainProductTitle/text()
</LongDescription>
```

Comment: The question is not entirely clear. In general, you want to use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) for resolving cross-references. -- P.S. Please see: [mcve]

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the child element which has the value in $subitem

Comment: As I said, it's not clear enough. And your code is incomplete and cannot be run as is. I took a guess and posted an answer. But that's not how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO xmlns:ns1="http://some.namespace.url">
    <ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
        <ns1:name>ABC</ns1:name>
        <ns1:numberInParent>1</ns1:numberInParent>
    </ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
    <ns1:productSpecificationComponent>
        <ns1:name>DEF</ns1:name>
        <ns1:numberInParent>1</ns1:numberInParent>
    </ns1:productSpecificationComponent>

    <ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
        <ns1:name>ABC</ns1:name>
        <ns1:mainProductTitle>
            <![CDATA[Description of ABC]]>
        </ns1:mainProductTitle>
    </ns1:specificationSectionDetail>.
    <ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
        <ns1:name>DEF</ns1:name>
        <ns1:mainProductTitle>
            <![CDATA[Description of DEF]]>
        </ns1:mainProductTitle>
    </ns1:specificationSectionDetail>
</ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://some.namespace.url"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="desc" match="ns1:specificationSectionDetail" use="ns1:name" />

<xsl:template match="/ns1:productSpecificationFullDTO">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="ns1:productSpecificationComponent">
            <Item>
                <Name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:name"/>
                </Name>
                <LongDescription>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('desc', ns1:name)/ns1:mainProductTitle"/>
                </LongDescription>
            </Item>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <Item>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
      <LongDescription>
            Description of ABC
        </LongDescription>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Name>DEF</Name>
      <LongDescription>
            Description of DEF
        </LongDescription>
   </Item>
</output>
```

Note that there is no need for a variable and certainly not any "concatenating variable value to the xpath".

Comment: Thanks for the response, however tried the same and it did result in an empty element. But the output you have shown is what expected

Comment: I am afraid I couldn't debug your code without seeing it even if I wanted to. In any case, the idea is to give you the general principle which you then adapt to your specific situation.